# jQuery click-function passing parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, click, closures

I would like to assign the jQuery click-function for all elements in an array. But additionally, I need to access the array from within the click-function. The source will hopefully make it clearer:

```
for (var i=0; i<mybox.myarray.length; i++) {
    mybox.myarray[i].jqelem.click(function(event, mybox) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        doStuffWithParameter(mybox);    
    });
}   

// mybox is a JavaScript object (not jQuery-element!), myarray is an array, jqelem is a jQueryelement ala $("div.myclass");
```

The problem seems to be with `function(event, mybox)`, apparently that doesn't work, i.e. `mybox` is `unknown` within the function. I think I 'kind of' understand why it cannot work this way, but how can this be achieved?

PS: I'm basically just doing it to save me from typing it manually for all array-elements.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the (useless) second callback function parameter named `mybox`.

If `mybox` is in scope in the outer block, it'll be in scope in the inner callback function too!

Should you need to know the appropriate value of `i` in the callback then you can do [event registration-time binding](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
for (var i=0; i<mybox.myarray.length; i++) {
    mybox.myarray[i].jqelem.click({i: i}, function(event) {  
        // use "event.data.i" to access i's value
        var my_i = event.data.i;
    });
}
```

The map `{i : i}` corresponds with the `eventData` parameter in the jQuery `.click()` documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. My actual problem was related to using the `i` within the inner function tough, and ShankarSangoli's answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

When your click handler gets called, the first argument is the event data. jQuery doesn't pass in a second argument.

**Update:** Using closure to get to `mybox` object (notice I removed the 2nd argument)

```
for (var i=0; i<mybox.myarray.length; i++) {
    mybox.myarray[i].jqelem.click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        // here's the trick to get the correct i
        (function(item) {
               return function() {
                         doStuffWithParameter(mybox.myarray[item]);
               };
         })(i);

        // you can access any object from parent scope here 
        // (except i, to get to right i, you need another trick), 
        // effectively creating a closure   
        // e.g. doOtherStuff(myarray)
    });
}
```

Read more on closures here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/
and here: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: You're misunderstanding my question. I don't want the DOM element, I want the object. ´mybox´ is a JavaScript object, not a jQuery-element!

Comment: In your update, have you just removed the 2nd parameter? Cauz that doesn't do it for me. `mybox` is then `unknown` within the function.

Comment: No it is not. I just edited my answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: Oh, then this must be because I'm using `doStuffWithParameter(mybox.myarray[i]);` in my actual code? So how can I solve that?

Comment: Actually, ShankarSangoli's answer explains exactly this case!

Comment: @Ben let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2028/discussion-between-mrchief-and-ben)

Comment: jQuery has built-in support for passing extra data to callback handlers - see use of `eventData` in `.bind()` etc.

Comment: Right, but will it solve this particular problem (of loop variable and evaluation scope)?

Comment: @Mrchief absolutely, yes. See my answer.

Comment: @Ben, you can use `data` attributes but IMHO, why incur the overhead when you can solve it with plain JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of jquery data attributes

```
for (var i=0; i<mybox.myarray.length; i++) {
    mybox.myarray[i].jqelem.data("arrayIndex", i).click(function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        doStuffWithParameter(mybox.myarray[$(this).data("arrayIndex")]);    
    });
}
```

Comment: technically this answer is still incorrect - the extra callback function parameter will mask the real variable in the outer scope.

Comment: Oh yeah I missed to remove that parameter, thanks @Alnitak I have edited my answer.